# Reorder rows in a dataframe with matching string

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe `df` that I would like to push all the rows that have "Date of diagnosis of metastases in xy" in the `Value4` col right below the rows that have "Location of extra-hepatic metastases" in the `Value2` col and "xy" in the `Value3` col.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Measurement = c(
    "Were extra-hepatic metastases detected?", "Were extra-hepatic metastases detected?",
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  Value = c(
    "yes", "no", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  Value2 = c(
    NA, NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA
  ),
  Value3 = c(
    NA, NA, "Peritoneum", NA, "Lymph_nodes", NA, "Lungs", NA, "Bones",
    NA, "Brain", NA, "Other", NA, "Other2", NA, "Other3", NA
  ),
  Value4 = c(
    NA, NA, NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in peritoneum",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in lymph nodes", NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in lungs",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in bones", NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in brain",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in “other” location",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in “other” location 2",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in “other” location 3"
  ),
  Value5 = c(
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
  )
)
```

I know I can do this with:

```
df_ordered <- df[c(1:3,11,4,12,5,13,6,14,7,15,8,16,9,17,10,18), ]
```

Expected output:

```
df_ordered <- data.frame(
  Measurement = c(
    "Were extra-hepatic metastases detected?", "Were extra-hepatic metastases detected?",
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  Value = c(
    "yes", "no", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA
  ),
  Value2 = c(
    NA, NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases", NA, "Location of extra-hepatic metastases",
    NA
  ),
  Value3 = c(
    NA, NA, "Peritoneum", NA, "Lymph_nodes", NA, "Lungs", NA, "Bones",
    NA, "Brain", NA, "Other", NA, "Other2", NA, "Other3", NA
  ),
  Value4 = c(
    NA, NA, NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in peritoneum",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in lymph nodes", NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in lungs",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in bones", NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in brain",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in “other” location",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in “other” location 2",
    NA, "Date of diagnosis of metastases in “other” location 3"
  ),
  Value5 = c(
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
  )
)
```

Is there a way to do the same without hard-coding in the row numbers and using tidyverse instead in combination with some regex?

Comment: The `df_ordered` you posted seems to be the same as `df`. That's different than `df_ordered <- df[c(1:3,11,4,12,5,13,6,14,7,15,8,16,9,17,10,18), ]`. It's not clear from your description why you are combing two values at a time. There are rows for Peritoneum/Brain in Value 3 and then in value 4, but why are those two values grouped together? Same with Lymph_nodes/other? Also the mismatch in how values are represented in value 3 and value 4 really complicates things. It seems `df` is already in the order you describe. Can you please double check the sample data?